# Get container name from current running app page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce-id

I am beginner in salesforce integration. I want to know that how can i get the name of container in which my salesforce application is running?

For example, If my page in injected in Opportunity then i want to know that current running object is opportunity. If its injected inside account the Accounts and so on..

Comment: What technology are you planning to use? Lightning Components? Visualforce? Something else? Please be more specific so we can provide you with the best possible answer.

Comment: I am using visualforce.

Comment: Off the top of my head the only way I can think to to this is to pass the record ID of the open record to Apex, and have it check the SObject type based off the ID, and return that. Hopefully someone else will know more, but I'm not sure if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

There is the idea: [System Enum to represent execution content Quiddity(Future/Batch/Queueable/Test)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003XnHQAU). That would give you some of the details you need.

Otherwise I'd look into the [`Apexpages.currentPage()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_ApexPages_currentPage.htm). With the PageReference it returns you could examine the query string parameters and relative URL for indications of where the Visualforce page is being used.

In scenarios where I've embedded a Visualforce page within the Opportunity layouts the Apex class has been an extension to the standard controller. As such you get an instance of [`ApexPages.StandardController`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm) in the constructor. That would also provide details about what type of record you are working with.